# Bind a property based on a dictionary key?

Tags: wpf, dictionary, binding, key

This seems to be a tricky one.
You have a data object which you bind to a number of user controls.
Simplified:

```
 public class Shift : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    private int _baseColor;
    public int BaseColor
    {
        get { return _baseColor; }
        set
        {
            _baseColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BaseColor");
        }
    }

    private Employees_E _employee;
    public Employees_E Employee
    {
        get
        {
            return _employee;
        }
        set
        {
            _employee = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Employee");
        }
    }
```

And here is the deal:
Depending on the Employee, the user control will change its background. One way to solve that (which works fine) is of course to use a converter, like...

```
Background="{Binding Employee, ElementName=uc, Converter={StaticResource EmployeeValueConverter}
```

But when all of it is dynamic it complicates things a lot. I don't know in advance the number of, or the name of the Employee, or the associated color to the employee.

What I want is my user control to bind to a Dictionary so that Shift.BaseColor binds to the value where the key is Employee. Something like:

```
Background="{Binding BaseColor, ElementName=anynamespace, Converter={StaticResource AnotherConverter}
```

Or preferable:

```
Background="{Binding MyDictionary[Employee].Value... with a converter...
```

The user will be able to change the associated color without changing the data object so I need another way to update my user controls when the color change.
The value will be an integer and in the converter I return a LinearGradientBrush form a list, so the integer will be an index in that list.

*UPDATE 1*

The background i will change is a Border background where Multibinding isn't possible? I have found another thread showing how to do it with multibinding but doesn't work in this case...?

*UPDATE 2*

The problem isn't how to get access to the values or the converter. The problem is when the user change the value in the dictionary and how to properly bind that to make the user control update it's background. Let's say we have a key=MARIA and a value of 21 which is the index of my List. Then the user control has a certain color. But the user might want to associate another color to that key, but there I can't figure out how to bind it.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SPAS.Controls.ShiftControl" ...
    <Border BorderThickness="1" x:Name="myBorder" Background="{Binding BaseColor, ElementName=uc, Converter={StaticResource BaseColorLinear}, Mode=TwoWay}" >
        ...
    </Border>
</UserControl>

public partial class ShiftControl : UserControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty BaseColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BaseColor", typeof(int), typeof(ShiftControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));
    public int BaseColor
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(BaseColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BaseColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty EmployeeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Employee", typeof(Employees_E), typeof(ShiftControl), new PropertyMetadata(Employees_E.VAKANT));
    public Employees_E Employee
    {
        get { return (Employees_E)GetValue(EmployeeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EmployeeProperty, value); }
    }...
```

I want the BaseColor to come from

```
Dictionary<Employees_E, int>
```

so the user can change either the Employee property or the value in the dictionary.

Comment: Why not just pass the dictionary to Shift?

Comment: just think it simply, the input here is of course the `uc` with the path `Employee`, the output is of course a Brush value (used for Background). So a `Dictionary` can just be a means to convert the string to the Brush. That means you still have to use a converter. Inside the `Convert` method, you need to access to the `Dictionary` to convert the key and return a Brush.

Comment: I don't think that will help in a case like this? Updated...